# How do I add another coordinate label in Xarray?

Tags: python, python-xarray, scientific-computing

I have an Xarray, say

```
da = xr.DataArray([[1,2],[1,2]],coords={'x':['param1','param2'],'y':['idx','idx2']})
```

This is a 2D data array. **As I build out my code, I would like to add another "column" or coordinate label to this 2D dataset.** Similar to how in Pandas I can just do

```
da['param3'] = [1,2]
```

To add that other column. Is there an equivalent method in Xarray?

Answer (score 1):

I would first create a second dataArray with the new data:

```
da2 = xr.DataArray([[1,2]],coords={'x':['param3'],'y':['idx','idx2']})
```

then combine them

```
da3 = xr.combine_by_coords([da, da2])
```

You get

```
<xarray.DataArray (x: 3, y: 2)>
array([[1, 2],
       [1, 2],
       [1, 2]])
Coordinates:
  * x        (x) <U6 'param1' 'param2' 'param3'
  * y        (y) <U4 'idx' 'idx2'
```

Comment: Thanks! This is not exactly what I was looking for because it's more of a workaround. Akin to using numpy.concatenate instead of lumpy append. But it does solve my problem.